# What is the emancipation process?

Tags: family-law, minor, pennsylvania, advice

I am looking into emancipation and was wondering what the process looks like. I live in PA. Any information will help.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of pages that are relevant, for example [this](https://www.lccpa.org/pathfinder/EmancipationMinorPathfinder.pdf) (Lehigh county), [this](https://www.palawhelp.org/resource/emancipation-of-minors)  written by MidPenn Legal Services, [this](https://www.palawhelp.org/files/A50D42DC-FCAA-1883-E79C-9619DF2007FA/attachments/24F525D6-4B5E-4E65-A857-9325F6655C7C/4_emancipation.pdf) (PAlawhelp) and [this](https://www.eriebar.com/public/e-law/emancipation) (Erie County). There is no statute regarding emancipation, which means that the courts deal with the issue on an ad hoc basis. The process is basically that you file a petition with the Court of Common Pleas, there will be a hearing, and the judge will issue a ruling. There is no specific form, instead you would need to hire an attorney to file a petition etc. The process focuses on the specific reason for emancipation, for example "for medical consent", or to get around the fact that you have to go to the school in the district where your parents live. Bear in mind that what emancipation means is "being treated as an adult", where no court order will give you the right to purchase alcohol under-age. No emancipation hearing is required to receive public assistance. The Erie county page gives more information on reasons where a court hearing is not required (rights that flow from already being married, and the complication of medical consent plus the higher bar that must be clear for an abortion). [This page](https://www.palawhelp.org/resource/family-law-manual) provides a general Pennsylvania Family Law manual.